# How can Doppler Shift be applied to Electromagnetic waves

Tags: doppler-effect

Doppler Shift applies (originally) to mechanical waves. Waves that are propagated in a medium.

Can anybody explain to me why EMW can get "Doppler Shifted" when they are self propagating "Vacuum" waves .

Comment: EM waves *do* have a medium: the electromagnetic field.

Comment: And what is this 'field' made of?

Answer (score 1):

the medium doesn't matter for Doppler effect. what matters is the finite speed of sound or light in this case. if you're moving towards the source of signal, due to the finite speed of light, you'll get the peaks in signal more frequently than if you were standing still.

Comment: The speed of sound is the distance traveled during a unit of time by a sound wave propagating through an elastic medium ie Air

Comment: vacuum is the medium too for EMWs